# Parse.com Open Endpoints for iOS

Tags: ios

I have an iOS app that uses a Parse backend.

Is it possible for someone to jailbreak their iPhone, decompile my app, modify the code and send custom requests to my Parse app backend using one's own app keys?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, and you don't even have to decompile your app. Security by obscurity (like hiding your API) is not the best option. Expect to receive custom request and harden against it.

Answer (score 2):

They don't have to modify your code -- I can use the BURP Suite to listen to the requests your app makes (by listening to network traffic) and then make my own requests in the same program. You should assume everyone knows how your Parse backend works, and lock it down tight.